# load server side .txt file into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to load a .**txt** file that looks like:

```
0,0:0
0,1:1
0,2:2
0,3:3
1,0:0
1,1:1
1,2:2
1,3:3
```

into a multidimensional JavaScript array called map_id[x][y].

`map_id[0][0] = 0;` because in the .txt file `0,0 = 0`.

Is it possible?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "Ajax".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **AJAX**. Because JavaScript is too hard to use for AJAX (Internet Explorer is guilty), you can use **JQuery**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.txt",                 // or path to file
    success: function(content) {
        // parse the content (content is the file content)
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

where parsing the content looks like this:

```
var lines = content.split('\n');
for ( var i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++ ) {
    // take index1, index2, value and store them in a 2d array (parse lines[i])
}
```

Comment: i dont under stand where index 1 and 2 come from

Comment: A line looks like this: `0,1:1`. This is `lines[i]`.
Just take 0 as `index1`, 1 as `index2` and 1 as value. Hint: `split`.